# Tiles clutter when moveToLatLong

Tags: ios, xcode, openstreetmap, route-me

I am using Route-Me with openStreetMap for my map.
I have a small button that updates the view to the current GPS location.
When this button is pressed I want the view to reset to the users position.  When I do that (I am using `[mapContents moveToLatLong:currentLocation]`) what happens is that tiles from different areas stick to the view and don't update. So the image is sliced into rectangles sometimes with different zoom levels.

What is the cause for this?